# How to get data in controller's method via ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I try asynchronously send data to controller's method. I suppose that's trivial challenge but did't fint the answer in SO. 
Here is my code:
**Controller**

```
public function actionRaiting(string $idUser, string $idBook, int $number )
{
    $model = new Raiting();
    $model->idBook = $idBook;
    $model->idUser = $idUser;
    $model->number = $number;
    if (\Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
    {
      if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()))
         $model->save();
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
$('.rating-input i').click(function()
{
     $.ajax(
     {
        url: 'raiting',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
               idUser: $('[name=idUser]').val(),
               idBook: $('[name=idBook]').val(),
               number: $(this).data("value") ,
            },
        dataType : 'json'
    });
});
```

I get the 400 error "not specified the required parameters".
Could you explain how should I do it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method expects the values as `GET` parameters. You are passing them in the `POST` body. Normally I would suggest appending the parameters to the url.

However, since you are saving data to a database, which should be done via `POST`, I suggest you remove the parameters from your function. Any validation to be done should be done in your model before the saving.

```
public function actionRaiting() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed type to GET and it helped!

Comment: @soju why so? I believe but really confused by choosing between request methods.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply try :

```
public function actionRaiting()
{
    $model = new Raiting();
    $model->idBook = $_POST['idBook'];
    $model->idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
    $model->number = $_POST['number'];
    // ...
}
```

And you should add csrf token to your request params, e.g. :

```
var csrfParam = $('meta[name="csrf-param"]').attr('content'),
    csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

And :

```
data: {
    csrfParam : csrfToken,
    // ...
}
```

Read more about :

- [Action Parameters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#action-parameters),
- [CSRF](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html#avoiding-csrf).

Comment: I tried and read about it, but couldn't cope with it. Changing type to `get` helped me!